# How to convert self join query into PySpark?

Tags: sql, database, dataframe, pyspark, alias

I need to convert this SQL code into PySpark:

```sql
SELECT 
    e.emp_id 'Emp_Id', e.emp_name 'Employee', m.emp_id 'Mgr_Id', m.emp_name 'Manager'
FROM 
    emp e
JOIN 
    emp m ON (e.manager_id = m.emp_id);
```

I tried this:

```py
empDF=spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", host).option("user", user).option("password",pwd).option("dbtable","EMP").load()

df1=empDF.alias("emp1").join(empDF.alias("emp2"), \
    col("emp1.manager_id") == col("emp2.emp_id"),"inner") \
    .select(col("emp1.emp_id"),col("emp1.name"), \
      col("emp2.emp_id").alias("manager_id"), \
      col("emp2.name").alias("manager_name")) \
   .show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: What do you get after you execute your script?

Comment: Are you getting any error. Since you are using ```.show()``` while creating new Data Frame the data will not show in the console if you are expecting so.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
df1 = (
    empDF.alias("emp1")
    .join(empDF.alias("emp2"),
          col("emp1.manager_id") == col("emp2.emp_id"),
          "inner")
    .select(
        col("emp1.emp_id").alias("Emp_Id"),
        col("emp1.emp_name").alias("Employee"),
        col("emp2.emp_id").alias("Mgr_Id"),
        col("emp2.emp_name").alias("Manager"))
)
df1.show(truncate=False)
```